# optimizing my Battleship field validator 4x4, and fix error

Tags: python

I'm a new to stackoverflow, recently I'm trying to solve a problem from codewar with Python 3x and it's about validating battleship location on a 10x10 grid. I passed 33 tests and failed 17 one, which is pretty bad, plus I sometimes get timeout error, so I figured there must be something wrong with my code, I'm open to listen to any opinion, can somebody help me?

```
def validate_battlefield(field):
    # important list comprehension !!!! to add element in a sublist infront and behind
    field = [[0] + k + [0] for k in field]
    extended_field = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    extended_field.extend(field)
    extended_field.extend([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
    field = extended_field
    # print(extended_field)

    list_of_battleship = []
    for h in range(1, 11):
        for w in range(1, 11):
            if field[h][w] == 1:
                m, n = h, w
                print("*****************")
                print(h, n)
                length_ship = 1
                field[m][n] = -1
                if field[h + 1][w] == 0 and field[h][w + 1] == 0:
                    list_of_battleship.append(1)
                    break

                while field[m][n + 1] + field[m + 1][n] + field[m][n-1] != 2:
                    if field[m][n + 1] == 1:
                        print(m, n + 1)
                        length_ship += 1
                        field[m][n + 1] = -1
                        n += 1
                        if field[m][n + 1] == 0:
                            list_of_battleship.append(length_ship)
                            break
                    if field[m + 1][n] == 1:
                        print(m + 1, n)
                        length_ship += 1
                        field[m + 1][n] = -1
                        m += 1
                        if field[m + 1][n] == 0:
                            list_of_battleship.append(length_ship)
                            break

    list_of_battleship.sort()
    if list_of_battleship == [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I can't get the following validation right, I really don't know where went wrong

```
print(validate_battlefield([
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],]
))
print(validate_battlefield(
    [
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]
))
```

Comment: Can you explain the objective of ```while field[m][n + 1] + field[m + 1][n] + field[m][n-1] != 2```? This is the check that seems to hang forever.

Comment: Because my algorithm is going from left to right, so it means if I encounter a slot that has a value of 1, the point will be m, n. Since I cannot have two 1 connected side to side, it adds the value right from m,n up from m,n and down from m,n. If it's 2, that means there's two 1 connected side to side, which is not allowed since the battleship can only be a straight line. Thank you!